# Why did English.SE create a new account for me?

Tags: support, user-accounts, linked-accounts

[My account on English.SE (user id 5724).](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/5724/user5724?tab=accounts)

I followed a link from [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/548600#548600) and tried to vote. SE told me to log in. When I did, SE told me it will create a new account.

That is despite the OpenID matching the one used and listed [here.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/156011/richard-aka-cyberkiwi?tab=accounts)

#### EDIT

If it wasn't entirely clear, when you click through the last link above to the SE account list, and hover over the English.SE card, it shows https://english.stackexchange.com/users/5614  **(5614)**

#### EDIT #2

A quote from balpha:

> You used a different google account to log in to english.SE.

It is so. I keep thinking the fact that I have logged on to some SE sites would transfer to other SE sites, regardless of which OpenID I have going at the time. This is very **confusing** and **annoying**, that the *Global Login™* is not really smooth.

Comment: Your accounts are linked...what's the question?

Comment: Well this is odd, you *already* have an account at http://english.stackexchange.com/users/5614/richard-aka-cyberkiwi, it shouldn't attempt to create a new account if you use the same OpenID

Comment: @bobby The question is as phrased in the question text. Please re-read. I have clarified with Yi Jiang's comment

Comment: You used a different google account to log in to english.SE.

Comment: *"Why did english.se create a new account for me?"* They think you're so nice, they added you twice.

Comment: Hello Richard and welcome to the site! Hello Richard and welcome to the site!

Comment: If you want to avoid the problem in the future, the other OpenIDs you think you might use to your list account.

Comment: @Borror0 That is a solution, yes, but <s>was</s> am trying to keep my other IDs.. *private*

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem on several of the StackExchange sites which I have used before and are listed in my profile: when I try to login there with my OpenID (same as before) the sites are suggesting they must create a *new* linked account. The first time it happened (on wordpress.stackexchange.com) I thought maybe I did something wrong, but now it just happened *again* on programmers.stackexchange.com! Bug?

Comment: This is still not fixed. Over two years later it just happened to me - on Web Applications.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a bug, or in fact anything to do with Stack Exchange. It is to do with whatever account you are currently logged into on the device you are using to browse.

For example, if I am logged in to my PC using a particular account, The Stack Exchange site will ask for credentials, and my current ones will be delivered. That might not be my preferred OpenID for SE, but the site cannot know that - so I always change to my preferred sign-in first.

So this is really a [pebkac](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK)...